# Shift + Mouse Wheel to scroll horizontally

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

I just need some help on how to scroll HORIZONTALLY by using 
(SHIFT + MOUSE SCROLL) IN WPF application.

```
private void RadGridViewRoomsSummary_MouseWheel_1(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{ ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
            scrollViewer.LineLeft();
        else
            scrollViewer.LineRight();
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

BY using a keyboard "**shift + mouse scroll**" I want to move a from left to right horizontally by specific windows.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ScrollViewer`, handle its `PreviewMouseWheel` event. Here's the handler:

```
private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;

    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
    {
        scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - e.Delta);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```